# Failed to resolve 'com.google.zxing:core:3.3.0'

Tags: android, zxing

I'm getting the following error in the Android Studio while build gradle and the library is not added in dependencies.

[image]

Comment: Try to invalid cache and restart.

Comment: if dependency doesn't work, then try downloading the jar directly and include it in lib folder of our project. [Link To Jar](https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/google/zxing/core/3.3.0/core-3.3.0.jar)

Comment: Have you included jcenter()  in your repositories ? @Vikas

Comment: `C:\D-drive` is an odd folder name

Answer (score 3):

First, check you can [reach this URL](https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/google/zxing/android-integration/3.3.0/)

If so, you need to add a repository

```
repositories {
    jcenter()
    mavenCentral() // add this
}
```

If not, check your internet connection

Then, you actually only want to `compile 'com.google.zxing:android-integration:3.3.0'` for Android projects and intergrating a BarcodeScanner Intent class.

That'll include the core for you

Answer (score 1):

Go to File->Invalidate Caches and Restart. Now update the repository. This process worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

have you add at project level gradle file?

```
allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
}
```

Comment: It's actually in `mavenCentral()`