# Flutter || build failed

Tags: flutter, dart

so im cloning some project from git and i already run `flutter pub cache repair` `flutter pub get` in administrator
i already search for this error but didn't find any answer

jdk version i use jdk-17.0.1 and jdk-11.0.14 both result the same.

```
* What went wrong:
Could not determine the dependencies of task ':app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'.
> Could not resolve all task dependencies for configuration ':app:debugCompileClasspath'.
   > Could not resolve com.google.zxing:core:{strictly 3.3.0}.
     Required by:
         project :app
      > Cannot find a version of 'com.google.zxing:core' that satisfies the version constraints: 
           Dependency path 'android:app:unspecified' --> 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:8.2.0' --> 'com.facebook.android:facebook-common:8.2.0' --> 'com.google.zxing:core:3.3.3'
           Constraint path 'android:app:unspecified' --> 'com.google.zxing:core:{strictly 3.3.0}' because of the following reason: debugRuntimeClasspath uses version 3.3.0

> Could not resolve com.google.zxing:core:3.3.3.
     Required by:
         project :app > com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:8.2.0 > com.facebook.android:facebook-common:8.2.0
      > Cannot find a version of 'com.google.zxing:core' that satisfies the version constraints: 
           Dependency path 'android:app:unspecified' --> 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:8.2.0' --> 'com.facebook.android:facebook-common:8.2.0' --> 'com.google.zxing:core:3.3.3'
           Constraint path 'android:app:unspecified' --> 'com.google.zxing:core:{strictly 3.3.0}' because of the following reason: debugRuntimeClasspath uses version 3.3.0
```

and if i switch to jdk-17.0.1 and add this line in gradle.properties

this line =

```
org.gradle.java.home=C:/Program Files/Java/jdk-17.0.1
```

it result this

```
What went wrong:

Could not initialize class org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.InvokerHelper
```

Comment: check this url, it may work to handle this error https://stackoverflow.com/a/45918606/6600475

Comment: it seems didn't work